# Play Framework POST route does not run when submitting a form

Tags: java, forms, playframework, routes

I have never run into this before, so I am looking for help.

I have a simple one field form that has a Submit button which will not kick off the POST route for it.  This code was working a few days ago, but now it just continually runs the GET route.  There is no error, since it never makes it to the POST route and the function it is calling.

Here are the routes:

```
GET    /createptp        controllers.Application.ptpCreate()
POST   /createptp        controllers.Application.ptpSave()
```

Here is the form:

```
@(ptpForm: Form[Application.PTPForm], lookups: java.util.List[Lookup], users: java.util.List[User])

@main(null) {

    <section id="ptpCreated">
        <form class="formoid-solid-dark"
            style="background-color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Roboto', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #34495E; max-width: 480px; min-width: 150px"
            method="get" action="">
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Success</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="element-number" title="This is the eight-digit Provider ID number that you used for this setting in the portal maintained by Xerox.  You may have had different Provider IDs for different services, settings, and/or waivers.  Cannot be blank - numbers only">
                <label class="title"><span class="required">* Legacy Provider Id...</span></label>
                <div class="item-cont"><input type="text" name="legacy_Provider_Id" class='allow_numeric' required="required" min="1" max="99999999" maxlength="8" placeholder=""/><span class="icon-place"></span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="submit">
                <input type="submit" value="Continue" />
            </div>
            <!-- This is needed for bottom shadow to appear... -->
            <div></div>
        </form>
    </section>

}
```

Here are the functions in the controller:

```
    public Result ptpCreate() {
            // Set some needed values...
            List<Lookup> lookups = Lookup.find.all();
            List<User> users = User.find.all();
            // Sort the lists...
            AppGlobals sortThis = new AppGlobals();
            Collections.sort(users, sortThis.new sortUsers());
            Collections.sort(lookups, sortThis.new sortLookups());
            return ok(adult1.render(form(PTPForm.class), lookups, users));
    }

public Result ptpSave() {
        Form<PTPForm> ptpEntry = form(PTPForm.class).bindFromRequest();

        if (ptpEntry.hasErrors()) {
            List<Lookup> lookups = Lookup.find.all();
            List<User> users = User.find.all();
            Logger.debug("Save ptp - errors");
            // Sort the lists...
            AppGlobals sortThis = new AppGlobals();
            Collections.sort(users, sortThis.new sortUsers());
            Collections.sort(lookups, sortThis.new sortLookups());
            return badRequest(adult1.render(ptpEntry, lookups, users));
        }

        String userkey = AccessMiddleware.getSessionUserKey();
        User user = null;
        user = User.findByUserKey(userkey);

        // Save the PTP record....
        PTP ptp = new PTP();
        PTPForm ptpForm = ptpEntry.get();

        ptp.setLegacy_Provider_Id(ptpForm.legacy_Provider_Id);

        ptp.save();

        return ok(ptpcreated.render(ptp.getPtpkey()));
    }
```

When I click the Continue button, it just goes back to the `ptpCreate()` function and does not even bother with the POST route.

I have performed a `clean` and `compile` with no luck.

I have tried changing the `<form action>` to `action="@routes.Application.ptpSave()"` with no luck either.

I am completely lost on this one since there are no errors to track down.

Comment: One thing you can try is to use browser dev tools (Network tab in FF). What happens when you submit the post request? What response are you getting?

Comment: Also remove `method="get" action="">` from your `form` tag and use the proper action route instead.

Comment: I wrote out the `<form>` tag again from scratch and it is working now.  Not sure why removing and writing this out again would fix it.  Works now.

Comment: The reason probably is you had a `method=get` in your form tag before. The request was `GET` not `POST` as the controller expected.

Comment: I have written an answer, please don't delete the question. It would be helpful if others can find the question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @jrook, you need to make sure the `<form>` tag uses a POST method. As shown in your question, your `<form>` has `method="get"`.

If you look in your routes, `GET /createptp` goes to `controllers.Application.ptpCreate()` whereas `POST /createptp` goes to `controllers.Application.ptpSave()`. They both have the same URL, so the method used to send the request is very important.

When you use `action="@controllers.routes.Application.ptpSave()"` you've got the right URL, but you're still sending a GET request so it will go to `controllers.Application.ptpCreate()` instead of `controllers.Application.ptpSave()`.

The fix is to use `method="POST"` to route to `controllers.Application.ptpSave()`.

An alternative is to use a form template helper to render the correct method and action given a reverse route. E.g. `@helper.form(action = controllers.routes.Application.ptpSave()) { ... }`. This will render `<form method="GET" action="/createptp">...</form>`. See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaFormHelpers#Creating-a-%3Cform%3E-tag.

In the future to debug something like this use two techniques:

1. Use *curl* to manually send a POST request to `/createptp` to check it works.
2. Use your browser's developer tools to test what kind of request you're sending when you submit a form.

I recently created a Play Framework issue to improve the documentation in this area: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/8004. If you have an thoughts about this feel free to leave a comment.